# Why am I getting an NodeMailer HELO 501 hostname error?

Tags: node.js, smtp, lets-encrypt, nodemailer, starttls

I am getting an NodeMailer error when I try to connect to my NodeMailer SMTP server (which happens to be on the same machine):

```
error:  { Error: Invalid HELO. response=501 Error: Syntax: HELO hostname: 501 Error: Syntax: HELO hostname
    at SMTPConnection._actionHELO (/home/hunter/projects/proxy-e/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:1139:27)
    at SMTPConnection._processResponse (/home/hunter/projects/proxy-e/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:762:20)
    at SMTPConnection._onData (/home/hunter/projects/proxy-e/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:558:14)
    at TLSSocket._socket.on.chunk (/home/hunter/projects/proxy-e/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:510:47)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:283:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:264:11)
    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:219:10)
    at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:639:20)
  code: 'EPROTOCOL',
  response: '501 Error: Syntax: HELO hostname',
  responseCode: 501,
  command: 'HELO' }
```

I am attempting to connect via:

```
let optionsTwo = {
    port: 465,
    host: 'mydomain.com',
    secure: true,
    name: 'mydomain.com',
    transactionLog: true,
    debug: true,
};

const connection = new SMTPConnection(optionsTwo);

connection.connect(function() {
    console.log("connected?");

    let authTwo = {
        user: 'foo',
        pass: 'bar'
    };

    connection.login(authTwo, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("err::", err);
        }
        console.log("logged in?");
    });

});

connection.on("error", function(err) {
    console.log("error: ", err);
});
```

My NodeMailer server:

```
let options = {
    secure: false,
    authOptional: false,
    secure: true,
    key: hskey,
    cert: hscert,
    ca: [hschain],
    onAuth(auth, session, callback) {
    ...
    },
}

const emailServer = new SMTPServer(options);

emailServer.listen(465);
```

My server has a registered domain name and a certificate from LetsEncrypt. I haven't been able to figure out why I continue to get this `HELO hostname 501 error`. From digging into the NodeMailer JS files I found this:

> Handles server response for STARTTLS command. If there's an error
>        * try HELO instead, otherwise initiate TLS upgrade. If the upgrade
>        * succeedes restart the EHLO

Which makes me assume that STARTTLS has some sort of error so it's attempting to use HELO and failing, but why?

Comment: I think you are missing auth credentials.Refer this [blog](https://www.programmingschool.io/how-to-send-emails-in-node-js/) or [github](https://github.com/deval93/NodeJS-RESTful-APIs/blob/master/api/controllers/mailController.js)

Comment: @Deval no I don't think it's that, because for one I'm already passing in credentials (see update) (`console.log('connected?')` never gets run) and two I'm not using NodeMailer's `createTransport` method, but their [STMP connection](https://nodemailer.com/extras/smtp-connection/).

Answer (score 1):

For some reason `name: 'mydomain.com',` is incorrect, and when removing it, I no longer get the error.